# Xcode 7.1 beta 2 - How to unblock ''run'' - ''test'' - ''dubug'' in the tools ''Product'' and ''Debug'' of the toolbar?

Tags: xcode

Actually, I have just downloaded Xcode 7.1 beta 2.

**Problem :**

I would try to run and execute my program, but the icons in the tools seem inaccessible, blocked. Is there a specific way to unlock these icons?

I have tried to modify some things in the setting, but it doesn't work.

---

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I can't connect scheme with target. Have I made a mistake?

---

[image]   How from this place can I can the target?

---

[image]

I'm not sure of the actual definition of a '' target '', but among them, which one should I choose?

---

[image]

This will be the last thing I'll ask you today. It seems there's compilation, but I can't watch them. Are you able to explain me what is happening? Is there a way to run my program from the terminal and observe the results?

Comment: Do you have target and scheme configured?

Comment: Target : http://imgur.com/k6HggsA

And scheme: http://imgur.com/vdFHS2O

Comment: No, I don't. Can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with missing target or scheme.

To Add target you have to click plus button

[image]

And choose a template, for example Commannd Line Tool for c++ application.

Then to add scheme you have to click

[image]

Then `New Scheme...` and connect scheme with target.

Comment: Can you just like my page. It is the only way I can sent you some pictures. I follow all your informations, but I can't connect scheme with target. I don't know how to unblock this thing.

Comment: What page? Post image somewhere and share links